# Symfony - Can't get a way to read the property (PropertyAccessor)

Tags: symfony, properties, entity

I develop with symfony a form for create tickets but when i try i got this error:

[image]

my function buildform from the file tickettype.php:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
  $builder
    ->add('Titre', TextType::class)
    ->add('Message', TextType::class)
    ->add('Date', DateTimeType::class, ['data' => new \DateTime()] )
    ->add('Demandeur', EntityType::class, [
      'class' => Client::class,
      'choice_label' => 'Nom',
     ])
     ->add('Agent', EntityType::class, [
       'class' => Dealer::class,
       'choice_label' => 'Nom',
     ])
     ->add('Etat_Ticket', EntityType::class, [
       'class' => Etat::class,
       'choice_label' => 'Statut',
     ]);
}
```

and in the controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("/add/", name="add_ticket")
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function addTicketAction(Request $request)
{
  $ticket = new Ticket();
  $form = $this->createForm(TicketType::class, $ticket);
  $form->add('send', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'créé un nouveau ticket']);
  $form->handleRequest($request);
    
  if($form->isSubmitted()){
    $ticket->setDate(new \DateTime());
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($ticket);
    $em->flush();
    
    return $this->redirectToRoute('List_ticket');
  }
    
  return $this->render("add.html.twig", array('form' => $form->createView())); 
}
```

and my entity Ticket have this property:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Etat::class, inversedBy="Etat_Ticket")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $Etat_Ticket;
```

link to the entity Etat which look like this :

```
/**
 * Etat
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="etat")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
 class Etat
 {
   /**
    * @var int
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
    */
    private $id;

   /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="statut", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
    */
    private $statut;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
      return $this->id;
    }

    public function getStatut(): ?string
    {
      return $this->statut;
    }

    public function setStatut(string $statut): self
    {
      $this->statut = $statut;

      return $this;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why the property etat_ticket is inversed by itself in annotation? Seems like a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a getter for `Etat_Ticket` property, so symfony (and that's a PHP common rule, when the property is not public) can't read its value from outside class scope. Symfony Form component, here, is trying by default to use the getter or access the property directly if it were public, and as neither getter nor public property are found, it symply doesn't know how to retrieve the value.

You can feed the form by yourself ([docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#data)) or use [`property_path`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#property-path).

Remember also that binding entities (or in general the domain model) directly to a form is good for RAD (rapid application development) but not so good in the long term. I would suggest to use a sort of DTO in order to read and write from and to the model (take a look [here](https://speakerdeck.com/el_stoffel/using-symfony-forms-with-rich-domain-models) in order to get an idea about this concept)